# Can 4 binary discrete random variables be independent if they all have to be the same?

Tags: probability

Suppose I have 4 binary random variables $X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4$.

Suppose $$P(1,1,1,1)=P(0,0,0,0) = 0.5$$ a so called "non-positive" distribution because some of the states have probability 0.

Now, without loss of generality, suppose I am given $X_1 = 1$. Then

$$P(X_i = 1 | X_1 =1) =1, i \in \lbrace 2,3,4\rbrace$$
$$P(X_i=1,X_j=1| X_1 =1) = 1, i,j \in \lbrace 2,3,4\rbrace, i\ne j$$
$$P(X_2,X_3,X_4| X_1 =1) = 1$$

So, we have the following conditional independence

$$P(X_2,X_3,X_4|X_1) = P(X_2 = 1|X_1 =1) P(X_3 = 1|X_1 =1) P(X_4 = 1|X_1 =1)$$

But how can $X_2, X_3, X_4$ be conditionally independent if I already know that, knowing one tells me the others? If I was given $X_2$, it would tell me the same thing that $X_1$ did right? So why does that make $X_2 \perp X_3,X_4 | X_1$?

Comment: How do you define *conditionally independent*?  Certainly, these are not *independent*... but *conditionally independent* won't follow the same definition as independent.  Why should you doubt the result that you see?

Comment: Recall that in the context of *independent* events (*ignoring conditional independence for now*) that the sure event is independent of any other event... including itself.

Answer (score 2):

If you're given the value of $\ X_1\ $, then you become *certain* of the values of all the other $\ X_i\ $, so if you're *then* told the value of $\ X_2\ $, that will give you no information about $\ X_3\ $ or $\ X_4\ $ that you don't already have.  The fact that $\ X_2\ $ *would have* given you the same information as $\ X_1\ $ if you *hadn't* been given the value of the latter is irrelevant once you suppose that you *have been* given it.